# PL/SQL collection in FUNCTION call issue

Tags: function, plsql, collections

I have a function MY_FUNC that takes a PL/SQL collection as a parameter.

**However, I get an error when I try to compile a package which has a procedure (MY_PROCEDURE) that calls MY_FUNC in an INSERT statement. Here is the procedure and the call to the function**

```
    MY_PROCEDURE (var1 IN OUT VARCHAR2, in_table_list IN OUT bf_types.table_of_addresses_type) 

    IS

    BEGIN

    INSERT INTO my_tab
    SELECT col_A,
           col_B, 
           MY_FUNC(var1, in_table_list)
    FROM json_table (json_str etc etc)

    END my_procedure;
/
```

**I get the following errors:**

541/3    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
561/3    PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "MY_FUNC": invalid
         identifier

561/3    PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
         'MY_FUNC'

561/42   PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Here is the code for MY_FUNC which compiles fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func (in_marketid IN VARCHAR2, in_list_of_addresses IN bf_types.table_of_addresses_type) RETURN DATE
IS
cnt INTEGER;
BEGIN
cnt := TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(in_marketid,1,1));
  RETURN(in_list_of_addresses(cnt).move_in_date);
END my_func;`
```

To test, I changed MY_FUNC to remove the PL/SQL collection parameter and modified my call.

i.e. CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func (in_marketid IN VARCHAR2) RETURN DATE

The code compliles so it seems there is a problem with calling a function in an INSERT statement if the function takes a PL/SQL table (collection) as a parameter. Also, please note that MY_FUNC has been declared outside the package.

I would be very grateful if anyone could help with this.

Comment: can you try with schema name.function_name in a call section

Comment: If schema name is schema1 then schema1.MyFunc

Comment: or remove the function call from insert statement and try to call the function normally in procedure.. and check weather it is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I get an error when I try to compile a package which has a
>   procedure (MY_PROCEDURE) that calls MY_FUNC in an INSERT statement.
>   Here is the procedure and the call to the function

I tried to simulate your situation and prepared something which you can use for your reference. Please read my inline comments.

```
--Created Object
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE  table_of_addresses_type IS OBJECT
(
  move_in_date date
);
--table of your object
create or replace Type v_table_of_addresses_type is table of  table_of_addresses_type;
/
--Table for inserting the record
CREATE TABLE my_tab(col DATE);
/
--Function
CREATE OR REPLACE   FUNCTION my_func(
            in_marketid          IN VARCHAR2,
            in_list_of_addresses IN v_table_of_addresses_type)
        RETURN DATE
    IS
        cnt INTEGER;
    BEGIN
        cnt := TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(in_marketid,1,1));
        RETURN(in_list_of_addresses(cnt).move_in_date);
    END my_func;
/
--Procedure
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE(
        var1          IN OUT VARCHAR2,
        in_table_list IN OUT v_table_of_addresses_type)
IS
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO my_tab
        SELECT MY_FUNC(var1, in_table_list) FROM dual;
    COMMIT;
END my_procedure;
/

--Calling / Exection:

DECLARE
    x v_table_of_addresses_type :=v_table_of_addresses_type();
    v_dt DATE;
    var1 VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
    x.EXTEND(3);
  --Populating the collection manually. You can populate it via a query as well
    x(1) := table_of_addresses_type(to_date('2017-05-21','YYYY-MM-DD'));
    x(2) := table_of_addresses_type(to_date('2017-05-22','YYYY-MM-DD'));
    x(3) := table_of_addresses_type(to_date('2017-05-23','YYYY-MM-DD'));
    --testing function call
    v_dt := MY_FUNC('111',x);
    dbms_output.put_line (v_dt);

    var1:= '111';
  --Calling Procedure. have to pass the var1 since its decalre as INOUT paramater in your procedure.
    MY_PROCEDURE(var1,x);

END;
/
--testing records from the table
Select * from my_tab
```

PS: You can wrap the procedure and function in a package which i didnot do in my answer.